# Running a model, only for the observations for which a variable is available, without including that variable

Tags: stata

I have data as follows:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/fullauto
```

Where `rep77` has some values that are missing.

I want to run the model below, without adding `rep77`, BUT only with the observations for which `rep77` is available, without dropping the missing values in `rep77`.

```
reg price foreign length mpg
```

Is there any way to do this in Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg price foreign length mpg if rep77 < . 

reg price foreign length mpg if !missing(rep77)
```